# parse JSON array with no object name typescript

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

I have an array of json object without having object name as

```
[
  {
    "FIRST_NAME": "fname",
    "LAST_NAME": "KSHHS",
    "SERIAL_NO": 905
  },
  {
    "FIRST_NAME": "jhdf",
    "LAST_NAME": "dfdf",
    "SERIAL_NO": 965
  }
]
```

I am trying to deserialize this in typescript where my class has different field name, the same way the we do in java using Jackson Object Mapper.
my class looks like:

```
       import { JsonObject, JsonProperty } from "json2typescript";
       @JsonObject("Student") 
       export class Student {
            @JsonProperty('FIRST_NAME', String)
            firstName?: string;
            @JsonProperty('LAST_NAME', String)
            lastName?: string;
            @JsonProperty('SERIAL_NO', number)
            id?: string;
    }
            let response: Student[];
            response = jsonConvert.deserializeArray(json , Student);//json is the Object array
```

I have tried using [json2typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2typescript) which could not deserialize as my json does not have object key but the example shown in the link has it.

There is no errors but it does not deserialize and I see empty Student in logs as below

```
Receiving JSON array:
[
  {
    "FIRST_NAME": "fname",
    "LAST_NAME": "KSHHS",
    "SERIAL_NO": 905
  },
  {
    "FIRST_NAME": "jhdf",
    "LAST_NAME": "dfdf",
    "SERIAL_NO": 965
  }
]

----------
Receiving JSON object:
  {
    "FIRST_NAME": "jhdf",
    "LAST_NAME": "dfdf",
    "SERIAL_NO": 965
  }
Returning CLASS instance:
Student {}
----------
Returning array of CLASS instances:
[ Student {} ]
----------
```

Answer (score 0):

Without an object key you basically have 2 options left:

1. Create a **WrapperObject**

```py
let wrappedJson = { "StudentArray": json };
response = jsonConvert.deserializeArray(wrappedJson, Student, "StudentArray");
```

2. **Loop** over your object:

```py
let response: Student[] = [];
for (let jsonObject of json) {
  response.push(jsonConvert.deserializeObject(jsonObject, Student));
}
```

Comment: I tried adding @JsonObject("Record") as it looks like it needs class identifier and removed private but still it did not

Comment: Can you describe exactly what problem you encounter?

Comment: It does not map the json to student object. It's student is empty as Returning CLASS instance:
Student {}
----------
Returning array of CLASS instances:
[ Student {} ]

Comment: I've seen another mistake, try the updated class

Comment: that was just a typo. I have it as LAST_NAME there. Question updated with logs

Comment: I think I found it, please let me know if that helped you